# Add a following 0 to inserted integer

Tags: sql-server

I am inserting a 3 or 4 digit integer into a table that needs the number to be 5 digits long.  How do I add a 0 following the 4 digit number and a leading and following 0 to the 3 digit numbers when they transfer?

Edit- This is part of a trigger defined as follows:

```
create trigger Trig on T2 
after insert, update, delete 
as  
  -- So that @@rowcount does not get affected by trigger code     
set NoCount on  
  -- If c3 column participated in update (it most certainly did in insert)
if update(C3)
begin
  -- Insert or update triggered this operation
 if exists (select * from Inserted)
  begin
         insert into P1 (C1, C2, C3)
         select T1.C2, T1.C3, T2.C3 --INFORMATION THAT NEEDS TO BE TRANSFERRED 
         from T1
         -- Inserted is a pseudotable holding inserted/updated data
         inner join inserted T2
         on T1.C1 = T2.C2
         where T2.C4 <> 9 --DETERMINES IF RECORD NEEDS TO BE TRANSFERRED
  end
     else
     -- Separate insert for deleted records
     -- To simplify inserting additional info for deleted records only
     begin
         insert into P1 (C1, C2, C3)
         select T1.C2, T1.C3, T2.C3 --INFORMATION THAT NEEDS TO BE TRANSFERRED
         from T1
      -- deleted is a pseudotable holding deleted/updated data
         inner join deleted T2
         on T1.C1 = T2.C2
         where T2.C4 <> 9 --DETERMINES IF RECORD NEEDS TO BE TRANSFERRED
     end
 end
```

Consider T2.C3 to be the pin number

Comment: If you need leading `0`s, then you shouldn't store these as numbers (if you are not treating them as numbers, don't store them as numbers, even if they just contain numerals). An example is phone numbers - you don't do arithmetics on phone numbers, so you shouldn't store them as numbers.

Comment: I didn't design the inital database.  I am building a tool to work with it.  I can't change the way the initial database stores info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to store this? Just add it to the query or create a view that does so:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(Number) + '0', 5) FROM dbo.TableName;
```

You can of course perform the same operation on the values as you're putting them into the table (either by modifying your insert statement or using a trigger if you have less control over DML).

Comment: I need to convert pin numbers on an INT format column to a Char(5) format column on another table. 3 digit pins have a 0 as teh first number but I need the initial zero to show up on the Char column.

Comment: Ok well if you are updating another table or insert from this table the same concept applies - pad each side of your source number with a 0, then take the right-most 5 characters.

Comment: So in my trigger it would look like: 'select c2, c3, right('0' +RTRIM(PIN) = '0', 5), c4 FROM dbo.card'  ?

Comment: I don't know, it's hard to read unformatted code in a comment. Maybe you can post your trigger code in full as a code sample in the question and it can be verified that way, especially since it's not complete (triggers don't usually just run a select, and usually you want to filter to the rows that are referenced in the trigger, not the whole table).

Comment: I don't understand why you're selecting from `dbo.card` and not from `inserted`. Do you really insert the entire `dbo.card` table every time you insert a single row or a handful of rows? Again, instead of describing the trigger, show it, otherwise I can't really tell you if it's right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Is this acceptable?

```
declare @PINs as Table ( PIN Int )
insert into @PINs ( PIN ) values ( 123 ), ( 4321 ), ( 12345 ), ( 5000 )
select Left( Right( '0' + Cast( PIN as VarChar(5) ), 5 ) + '0', 5 )
  from @PINs
```

It requires that PIN values are greater than 99 as per your problem statement.